# Font Awesome Pro not showing solid icons, just outlined icons?

Tags: font-awesome

I recently noticed that my font awesome icons are showing just the outline of icons and not the solid icons. I debugged conflicting plugins and its nothing that is conflicting. Im using FA Pro 5.1.15 and SVG/JS. Im guessing that is a problem with my kit js file? Im confused, because it worked fine before

HTML

```
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-notes-medical"></i>
  </div>
```

JS

`<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/52a14562ef.js"></script>`

https://jsfiddle.net/EdgarAlexPoe/q3n56a7c/3/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I had `far` instead of `fas` and that was the issue. Derp